Is "Understanding CDOs" in scope?
Is the "Understanding CDOs" question in scope here?
I see that it hasn't been closed, thus I've even participated a bit myself. But isn't it not quantitative enough for Quant.SE? I know it may be hard to find an appropriate StackExchange site for this, but I wanted to know what you think about it.
Personally, I thought that Money.SE would fit better. Though the OP seems not convinced it would be good enough. ;-)
I suppose my proposal could target such questions (not quantitative, but too "behind the curtains" for general money and personal finance). Would it be OK if I suggested in the original question the OP follow my proposal?

well, I kind of tried to start towards an answer, but the question that I think the original poster really is trying to ask ("what caused the financial meltdown?") could only be answered by a book. 

I thought the question was pretty ignorant as well, but the OP claims that he put effort into it already, so it doesn't just sound like a Wikipedia referral. Perhaps he just needs to read a book watch a ten-minute animation about how the financial system works.

Please, don't get me wrong. I wasn't implying his ignorance. And I can't complain about non-quant questions that much - in fact I feel much more comfortable in general finance (I still feel I am, as you called it, an "aspirational quant", hope you can tolerate me :-)). It's just that I got the impression, that you guys were rather strict when it comes to what is on-topic here. I have nothing against it, I was just a bit surprised.
